# Cannot link library for macOS-arm64 with executable for macOS-arm64

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries, linker-errors, linker-warning

I have some trouble with creating a build system on a **Monterey M1 MacBook**:

So far I have a working Makefile to build and link a library.
(simplified: `g++ -c` all .cpp files into .o files → `ar -r <.o files> libmyLibrary.a`>

→ *works great*

**THE PROBLEM:**
When I try to build an executable binary that uses said `libmyLibrary.a`. The compilation of source files works fine, but I get the following (seemingly nonsensical) linker warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Path/to/lib/libmyLibrary.a,
building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
```

→ I ofc then get some `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: ... <stuff from library> referenced from: <stuff from executable>`

How can building for the same target as the library be a problem?

Comment: What does `file libmyLibrary.a` report?

Comment: makefile executes `ar -r /path/to/lib/libmyLibrary.a src/stl.hpp.gch <lots of .o files>`
->
`ar: creating archive /path/to/lib/libmyLibrary.a`

Comment: `ar -t libmyLibrary.a` lists: `__.SYMDEF, stl.hpp.gch, all the .o files`

Comment: `file libmyLibrary.a` reports `libmyLibrary.a: current ar archive`

Comment: Rats, not what I was hoping for.  Do you still have the `.o` files lying around?  If so, running `file` on one of those will tell you what architecture it contains.  If not, you can extract them from your library with `ar` and then do it.

Comment: `file SomeFile.o` tells me `SomeFile.o: Mach-O 64-bit object arm64` for .o files from the library – and `main.o: Mach-O 64-bit object arm64` for the executable and all its .o files.
It also prints `stl.hpp.gch: data` for my precompiled header, which I guess is correct.

Comment: Hmmm, looks fine.  I think you should show us your Makefile.  I don't use make personally, but I'm sure there are people here who do.  And of course I have to ask you: why not use Xcode?  I'm doing pretty much what you're doing (although in my case I'm building a fat binary) and it works OK.

Comment: Thanks anyways, I'll keep digging a little deeper. I'd just keep using XCode but the library is used by an executable running on a raspberry pi, as well as my Mac, so I thought a makefile would work best.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by having an incompatible version of `ar` installed in your system. `ar` in homebrew binutils seems to be broken. This can be resolved by symlinking `llvm-ar` over `ar`, or using the system `ar`.

Comment: This is the right answer. The `ar` program in your system must be broken if you see this message. I ran `brew install llvm@12` and then used `llvm-ar` instead of `ar` and the error went away

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile the executable after changing how I link my library. My Makefile also linked a precompiled header `.pch` file.

After removing that, it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting.  Pretty unhelpful error message from `ld`, if that was the root cause.